# Copy columns and edit one column with different entries in a table

Tags: mysql

Copy 1st 2 rows in same table and insert it with edited column as shown below.

```
Table 1 (ID is auto increment)
        ID | CL1 | CL2   | CL3
        1  | A   | text1 | NULL
        2  | B   | text2 | NULL

Table 2 
            ID  | CL3
            21  | 45
            24  | 63

Converted Table 1
        ID | CL1 | CL2   | CL3
        1  | A   | text1 | NULL
        2  | B   | text2 | NULL
        3  | A   | text1 | 45
        4  | B   | text2 | 63
```

I know how to copy and insert all the rows with one column duplicated, but changing some column with different value is the problem.

Below is the query to copy all fields with 1 column changed:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3)
     SELECT col1, col2, 1
     FROM table1 LIMIT 2;
```

Ex: So now we have table2 which has table1 CL3's values. Now can we get the data from another table and insert them while copying?

Comment: are you saying you want the old ID value in column 3 of the copied data?

Comment: ID will be autoincremented, thats why i've left ID from above mentioned table.

Comment: yes, but I mean the value of column 3. From the sample data it looks like the value you want to be inserted in col3 is actually always the value the of "ID" column in the old record. Is that right, or just coincidence?

Comment: no actually i take field from another table. Maybe you can consider like a list (1,2,3,4,...) any number. Here i've given only 2 records for simplicity. It can increase and col3 numbers can be any number

Comment: so you need to join onto that table to get the value? on what field should the join be made?

Comment: yes but what values do you want to put in it? Using static values (like your current statement), every row you insert will get the same value in CL3 (i.e. "1"). If you want a  different value in the row, you have to look it up from somewhere, such as another table, or another column within table1. You need a source for your data.

Comment: that is the solution i am looking for. You can think of getting it from same table of some column, but i want dynamic values.

Comment: by "dynamic" values, do you mean random numbers? If not, then there must be some sort of pattern to what the values are, which you need to describe for me.

Comment: any hope? we can use functions to do that but, i wanted to know if we can do it with queries alone. Please let me know if any such ideas.

Comment: I'll ask again. Have you got the data you want to put in col3 already in another table? If so, what's the definition of the table? If you've got that, then you can do this with queries

Comment: I actually edited my question and added another table. Yeah it will come from another table. I got the solution also. **Solution is:  INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3)
     SELECT col1, col2, tables2.col3
     FROM table1, tables2 LIMIT 2;**
But many thanks for the efforts you have put for this.

Comment: Hmm, I believe that will give you a cross join. i.e. you will get every combination of all the records from both tables. So if you have 100 records in table1 and 6 records in table2 you will get 600 records inserted: each row in table1 will be shown 6 times, once for each possible row from table2. is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah correct, i wanted the same. Thank you for explaining the query.

Comment: ok just checking. It's a relatively unusual thing to do that's all. Most queries tend to involve inner or left joins. But if it's what you need then great.

Comment: that is just a temporary patch. we were suppose to manually enter some 18 rows like this. So tried to query it out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the first 2 records from 1 table updated with the values from the 1st 2 rows from another table, then I think you will need to add a sequence number to each one and join based on that.

Something like as follows, but it won't be quick!

```
INSERT INTO table1 (ID, CL1, CL2, CL3)
SELECT NULL, a.CL1, a.CL2, b.CL3
FROM
(
     SELECT CL1, CL2, @cnt1:=@cnt1 + 1 AS cnt
     FROM table1 
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt1:=0) sub0
     ORDER BY ID
     LIMIT 2
) a
INNER JOIN
(
     SELECT CL3, @cnt2:=@cnt2 + 1 AS cnt
     FROM table2 
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt2:=0) sub0
     ORDER BY ID
     LIMIT 2
) b
ON a.cnt = b.cnt
```